# How to make sure that a PHP page is called from my mobile app

Tags: php, android, ios, server-application

I have an iOS/Android app and I want to convert some of its functionality to webview, as this will make minor changes easier as I will only have to update the web app, rather than updating both iOS and Android and wait the review process.

I already have a PHP-mysql server app and use various server-client communication, so I am adding to this server app the pages I will display in my mobile app webview. The drawback here, is that if I typed the url and passed the same parameters in any browser, it will work, and I do not like that.

How to make sure inside my PHP code, that the page is being called from inside my own app?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Ultimately, you can't completely prevent this from happening.  Any sufficiently technical user can watch how your application is making the request, and replay it outside of your application.  The only thing you can really do is make this process more difficult.

Comment: you will have to install php server on your Android phone to run php directly -- it works as i tried it about a year ago -- but thats not going to help if your app is nothing but personal